# code shown below give no compile time error beside using new keyword

Tags: c++, heap-memory

This code snippet:

```
int* fun()
{
  int t=10;
  int *pointer=&t;
  return pointer;
}

int main()
{
  int* p = fun()
  cout<<*p;
}
```

as the above variable t goes out of scope as the function call ends and pointer storing address of variable that does not exist gives no error and works properly....confused why why??

Comment: As the target says, what you have is UB. That means anything can happen, including appearing to give the right result. This is, of course, not guaranteed.

Comment: fwiw `return &t;` would let gcc issue a warning https://godbolt.org/z/hf4qxoKob. You already obfuscated the matter enough such that gcc nor clang dont bother to diagnose. Concerning "works properly": try to turn on compiler optimizations

Comment: Just because a C++ program runs and appears to give the right result does not guarantee that it's bug free. This is actually a very important lesson to learn.